# Is "...つもりだったでしょうか" an OK translation for "Did you mean to ...?"

Tags: grammar, translation, nuances

A person planning a seminar wrote the date and day of the week, but the day of the week was incorrect. So I wanted to send a message asking "Did you mean to write ...?", but I'm struggling to wrangle a natural-sounding translation.

The closest I can come up with is 「(土)を書くつもりだったでしょうか。」but for some reason something about it doesn't sit right with me. Could someone with a better "natural Japanese" filter give a better idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose *do you mean to* would require some modifications depending on what you are asking.

Speaking backward, つもりですか/つもりでしたか normally sounds like *do you plan to/did you plan to...?*. That is, it sounds asking about the explicit plan, not implicit intentions. So if a sentence can be rewritten as *do you plan/try to...?*, つもりですか probably can be used.

As for the particular example, suppose (this year) there is written 3月19日（日）（＝actually 土曜日） we normally say

1. 日付と曜日が食い違っていますが、どちらが正しいでしょうか？
2. 19日は土曜日ですか、曜日のほうが間違っているということでよろしいでしょうか？
3. 19日は土曜日ですが、20日の間違いということでよろしいでしょうか？

In 1. you generally ask about the inconsistency; in 2, you assume the day of the week is wrong; in 3, you assume the date is wrong.

Slightly more generally, I guess you need to rephrase the English to something like "Currently X (which puzzles me), did you mean to write Y?", and translate it as "Xとなっていますが、Yということでよろしいでしょうか" (with possibly many modifications depending on the context).

Comment: Thanks for the clear suggestions. Could you point to somewhere explaining ということでよろしいでしょうか?  I haven't seen that pattern before, I'm not sure how it changes the meaning from 間違っているでしょうか or (20日が?)間違いでしょうか.

Comment: @Hikonyan It can be seen as an interrogative form of [ということだ](https://www.nihongokyoshi-net.com/2018/08/31/jlptn3-grammar-toiukotoda). The conveyed meaning of Xということでいいですか is  *Is my understanding correct that X?*. This sounds kind of indirect than just saying Xは間違いですか？.